# Работа с сенсором в Андроид

Tags: android

Привет.

Есть некоторая область из слотов (квадратов) как указано на рисунке.
Коснувшись пальцем определенного слота необходимо движением пальца выделить определенное слово.

Так вот вопрос собственно в том, как наиболее эффективно и при помощи каких Layout-ов лучше реализовать такую область (состоящих из так называемых слотов) и как рассчитать куда пользователь ведет пальцем (не отрывая его от экрана) и какие уже слоты выбрал.

Где можно прочитать об этом подробнее.

[image]

Благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А Вам нужен всего один View.  Для начала посмотрите вот этот пример игры [крестики-нолики](https://code.google.com/p/andoid-tictactoe). Все фишка в том, что просто отслеживаем текущие координаты, куда прикоснулся пользователь, потом решаем - нужно показывать меню или  подсвечивать.

Если глянуть правде в глаза, то подсветка - это просто. В момент нажатия рассчитываем клетку и записываем в массив состояния клеток новое состояние клетки и вызываем отрисовку. Она вызовет метод OnDraw, в котором на основании массива состояний рисуется правильная картина мира.

Comment: Спасибо. А как разбить на клетки, если использую всего 1 view? да и какой например view? Их же много.

Comment: Пример смотрели? нужен базовый View. От него делается наследник. А все клеточки - рисуются самостоятельно. Это дает очень большой простор для фантазии.

Comment: В целом идея ясна. Буду копать. Благодарю.